# python - multiply and add each element in list a with list b

Tags: python

function:

def unique_common(a, b):

I have two lists, lets say:

```
a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

and another list

```
b = [5, 8, 4, 1, 11].
```

This list b gives you the per item price for each item corresponding to the first list a.

For example, if you want to purchase 2 units of the first item, each unit costs $5 per item, to purchase the 3 units of second item it costs $8 per item, and so on.

I want to write a function that calculates the total price for the items in list a. For the example, the result would be

160 = 2*5 + 3*8 + 5*4 + 7*1 + 9*11

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 4):

With `sum` and `zip`:

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> b = [5, 8, 4, 1, 11]
>>> sum(count*price for count, price in zip(a,b))
160
```

> could you please tell how to give a lists a and b as parameters to a function like def unique_common(a, b)

```
>>> def total_price(a, b):
...     return sum(count*price for count, price in zip(a,b))
... 
>>> a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> b = [5, 8, 4, 1, 11]
>>> total_price(a, b)
160
```

Comment: could you please tell how to give a lists a and b as parameters to a function like def unique_common(a, b):

Comment: @rdeep sure, that's very easy. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

And also you can use `map` :

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9] 
>>> b = [5, 8, 4, 1, 11]
>>> sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], zip(a, b)))
160
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the solution would be to use NumPy, where the code should be very self-explanatory :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,3,5,7,9])
b = np.array([5,8,4,1,11])

c = a*b
d = np.sum(c)
print(d)
```